# Toggle between dark and light theme based on browser setting by default without requiring user to login

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, dark-mode

Currently, an individual has to login, then go to Preferences -> System Setting to make SO choose the Dark or Light theme by default based on browser configuration.

It would be much nicer if SO's default setting without a login would be *System Settings* which would let us access the Dark theme without logging in.

The preferences portion would preferably be retained for those who wish to use the Dark Theme on a Light Theme browser and vice versa via login or a toggle button in the UI to select the theme without logging in for those who wish to override the default setting.

Comment: Browsers don't expose their internal system settings to web pages loaded in the browser windows in order to do what you suggest

Comment: There exists this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840168/how-to-detect-if-the-os-is-in-dark-mode-in-browsers and this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56393880/9515207 Seems theoretically possible

Comment: @charlietfl modern browsers most certainly do. Which is how SO's default System Setting theme works. SO in effect already has support for this. You can check CertainPerformance's links for how it works in practice. I personally just wish for this feature to be made accessible without signing in. YouTube and Twitter are examples of websites which do so without logins